# Guess the Subset Strategy

Tags: algorithm

### Guess the Subset Game

The game works like this. You play against an adversary.

**Setup**

- There is a fixed set of numbers **A** (such as {1, 2, ... , 30})
- The adversary chooses a secret subset **S** by removing up to **k** elements (such as 0-5).

**Objective**

You know **A** and **k**, and your job is to figure out the subset by making guesses.

**Guessing**

You guess a subset **B**.

The adversary tells you **Yes** if **B ⊆ S** (i.e. if all of the elements that you guessed are in the secret subset **S**) and **No** otherwise.

---

**Question**

What strategy can you use to figure out the subset in the fewest number of guesses?

---

**Playable Version**
You can play the game here. Choose A and k, and you can make guesses. Reveal the Secret when you think you have it figured out. Re-run the snippet to try again.

```js
// Random Integer in [min, max)
const getRandomInt = (min, max) => {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
};

class GuessSubsetGame extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      numGuesses: 0,
      guess: '',
      prevGuesses: [],
      revealed: false
    };
  }
  
  isValid = (guess) => guess
     .split(',')
     .map(val => val.trim())
     .every(element => this.props.secret.includes(element)) ? 'Yes' : 'No';
  
  onSubmit = (e) => {
    this.setState((state, props) => ({
      guess: '',
      numGuesses: state.numGuesses + 1,
      prevGuesses: [{guess: state.guess, valid: this.isValid(state.guess)}, ...state.prevGuesses]
    }));
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  
  renderPrevGuesses() {
    return this.state.prevGuesses.map(({guess, valid}) => {
      return (
        <div>
          {valid} - {guess}
        </div>
      );
    });
  };
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.revealed ? 'Secret was ' + this.props.secret : <button onClick={() => this.setState({revealed: true})} >Reveal Secret</button> }
        <div>
          {'Guess Number: ' + this.state.numGuesses}
        </div>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <div>
            <label for="guess">Guess a Subset (like 1,2,3): </label>
            <input 
              type="text" 
              name="guess" 
              id="guess"
              value={this.state.guess}
              onChange={(e) => this.setState({guess: e.target.value})} />
          </div>
          <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Guess" />
          </div>
        </form>
        <div>
          <div>History</div>
          {this.renderPrevGuesses()}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class GuessSubsetGameCreator extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {    
      isBuilt: false,
      A: '1,2,3,4,5,6',
      k: 2,
      secret: null
    };
  };
  
  onSubmit = (e) => {
    const actualK = getRandomInt(0, parseInt(this.state.k) + 1);
    const aAsArray = this.state.A.split(',');
    const shuffled = aAsArray.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random());
    const secret = shuffled.slice(0, shuffled.length - actualK).sort();
    this.setState({
      isBuilt: true,
      secret
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  };
  
  render() {
    let result;
    if (!this.state.isBuilt) {
      return (
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <div>
            <label for="A">What are the elements of A? </label>
            <input 
              type="text" 
              name="A" 
              id="A" 
              required 
              value={this.state.A}
              onChange={(e) => this.setState({A: e.target.value})} />
          </div>
          <div>
             <label for="k">How many elements can be removed? </label>
             <input 
               type="number" 
               name="k" 
               id="k" 
               required 
               value={this.state.k}
               onChange={(e) => this.setState({k: e.target.value})} />
          </div>
          <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Start Game" />
          </div>
        </form>
      );
    }
    else {
      return <GuessSubsetGame A={this.state.A} secret={this.state.secret} />
    }
    return result;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <GuessSubsetGameCreator />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```css
div {
  padding-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

---

**Thoughts**

- If **k = size of A**, I don't think we can do any better than guessing each element one at a time. i.e. {1}, {2}, {3}, ... , {30}, because each element's inclusion is independent of every other. This gives 30 guesses in the example above.
- If **k = 1**, we could start by guessing **A** to see if no element was removed, and then find the missing element with a binary search. This gives about 6 guesses in the example above.
- I'm still trying to puzzle out **k = 2**.
- It seems a bit like mastermind which has been solved [see this puzzling.stackexchange question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/546/clever-ways-to-solve-mastermind), but in mastermind the adversary tells you how many of your guess are right, instead of just Yes/No.
- By the way, I ran into this problem while trying to update 30 library dependencies for a software module. The build failed after updating all of them, but I strongly suspected that no more than 5 of them were causing the build to fail. (In this case, I got some more information from the logs about which one failed than a single No which helped, but it was still a lengthy process since testing the build takes about 5-7 minutes per guess).

Comment: The best solution would be just to guess every number. It is never beneficial to guess larger subsets. After asking about every number you have B... but like you mentioned if k is not arbitrary you can do better

Comment: Well, If the input is set **A** and **K** numbers, then I think it's impossible to find a faster way than trying all possible **B**. BUT, if, and only if you have a helper input like a number in **B** range. That's will help too much.

Comment: @MitchelPaulin: Re: "if k is not arbitrary you can do better": Doesn't that contradict the rest of your comment? After all, the entire question is about the case where *k* is not arbitrary.

Comment: Are you trying to minimize the *worst-case* number of guesses, or the *average-case* number of guesses? If *k* is greater than |A|/2, then the worst-case number of guesses is certainly not better than |A|, because in that case there are more than 2^(|A|-1) possible choices of the secret subset *S*, so there's no way to distinguish all of them with only |A|-1 bits of information.

Comment: @j_random_hacker When k=1, the adversary can choose to remove either 0 or 1 elements from the set.

Comment: If you partition |A| into k+1 parts (which need not even be of equal size), at least one of those parts must yield a "yes" answer when used as a query.  This is not necessarily part of an optimal solution, but might be a useful heuristic.

Comment: @ruakh I was going for worst-case. I like the reasoning about the k > |A|/2, I just ran the numbers for |A|=5 and k=3. There are 26 subsets the adversary could choose (5 choose 5) + (5 choose 4) + (5 choose 3) + (5 choose 2), and since we only get one bit of info each guess (Yes/No) we would need at least log2(26) ~= 4.7 guesses, which rounds up to 5 since there's always a whole number of guesses.

Comment: With |A|=5 and k=2, there are 16 subsets, which means it would be possible to win in 4 guesses if you could cut the possibilities exactly in half with each guess. Unfortunately, that doesn't work for the first guess. Guessing one element splits it 11-5 and guessing two elements splits it 7-9.

Comment: More generally, partitioning A into k+m parts and using each part as a query must yield at least m "yes" answers.  It's reasonable to suppose that making all parts as equal in size as possible is best in the worst case.

Comment: The way to solve this exactly is by framing it as a minimax game tree. If it could be proven that it's never beneficial to make a query that involves elements from two disjoint earlier queries, then the state space and number of "player" moves shrinks: in this case, the complete state at any point in time can be described by k, plus a list of *the sizes of* disjoint subsets of A, each of which we know contains at least one element not in S; on each "player" turn, he must choose one of these subsets, and a number less than its size. But I suspect that such "combining" queries can be beneficial.

Comment: Addenda to my previous comment: the same logic actually applies if *k* ≥ |A| / 2 (not only if *k* > |A| / 2), and it would also actually apply to the average case as well (not just to the worst case), assuming we average over all possible choices of *S*.

Comment: Is there any interest in my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following C++ program will report the length of an optimal strategy, computed according to a generalisation of the minimax game tree strategy I mentioned in a comment, and using dynamic programming for speed.  It can optionally output a trace showing a maximum-length sequence of queries under this strategy.  (It would not be difficult to output the entire tree, but as this could be a nearly complete binary tree with more than 20 levels, it's not very interesting to a human.)

Essentially it turns out that the complete state of knowledge about all elements *can* be represented succinctly, even if we allow queries that involve elements from multiple different earlier queries.  A state of knowledge is represented in the program as a vector in which the first element is k, the second is the number of items in A about which we know nothing (I forgot about this aspect of state in my comment), and all remaining vector elements are the sizes of disjoint "marked" subsets of A, listed in increasing order.  A "marked" subset is a subset that we know misses at least one element of S.  Knowledge state vectors are always normalised (see the `normalise()` function).  The same vector representation is used for representing a "player move" (a choice of some number of elements from each of the disjoint subsets of A), even though the first element (where k would be) is meaningless in this context.

One surprise was the discovery that there exist worst-case sequences of queries that cause loops in the sequence of knowledge states -- that is, there are query sequences that are infinitely long in the worst case.  Fortunately the DP could be adjusted to take care of this.

To run the program, specify k as the first command-line parameter and |A| as the second.  To add a traceback showing a particular maximum-length sequence of queries under the optimal strategy, give `-t` as the first parameter.

For example, running `fewest_tests -t 5 30` produces:

```
Minimum number of queries required in the worst case: 20
One possible maximum-length sequence of queries that follow an optimal strategy:
Height=20.  Knowledge state: [5 30]
Choose [0 3]: Adversary replies YES.  (Other answer also leads to height-19 subtree.)
Height=19.  Knowledge state: [5 27]
Choose [0 3]: Adversary replies YES.  (Other answer also leads to height-18 subtree.)
Height=18.  Knowledge state: [5 24]
Choose [0 3]: Adversary replies YES.  (Other answer also leads to height-17 subtree.)
Height=17.  Knowledge state: [5 21]
Choose [0 2]: Adversary replies YES.  (Other answer also leads to height-16 subtree.)
Height=16.  Knowledge state: [5 19]
Choose [0 2]: Adversary replies YES.  (Other answer also leads to height-15 subtree.)
Height=15.  Knowledge state: [5 17]
Choose [0 2]: Adversary replies YES.  (Other answer also leads to height-14 subtree.)
Height=14.  Knowledge state: [5 15]
Choose [0 2]: Adversary replies YES.  (Other answer also leads to height-13 subtree.)
Height=13.  Knowledge state: [5 13]
Choose [0 1]: Adversary replies YES.  (Other answer leads to height-11 subtree.)
Height=12.  Knowledge state: [5 12]
Choose [0 1]: Adversary replies YES.  (Other answer also leads to height-11 subtree.)
Height=11.  Knowledge state: [5 11]
Choose [0 1]: Adversary replies YES.  (Other answer also leads to height-10 subtree.)
Height=10.  Knowledge state: [5 10]
Choose [0 1]: Adversary replies YES.  (Other answer also leads to height-9 subtree.)
Height=9.  Knowledge state: [5 9]
Choose [0 1]: Adversary replies YES.  (Other answer also leads to height-8 subtree.)
Height=8.  Knowledge state: [5 8]
Choose [0 1]: Adversary replies YES.  (Other answer also leads to height-7 subtree.)
Height=7.  Knowledge state: [5 7]
Choose [0 1]: Adversary replies YES.  (Other answer also leads to height-6 subtree.)
Height=6.  Knowledge state: [5 6]
Choose [0 1]: Adversary replies YES.  (Other answer also leads to height-5 subtree.)
Height=5.  Knowledge state: [5 5]
Choose [0 1]: Adversary replies YES.  (Other answer also leads to height-4 subtree.)
Height=4.  Knowledge state: [5 4]
Choose [0 1]: Adversary replies YES.  (Other answer also leads to height-3 subtree.)
Height=3.  Knowledge state: [5 3]
Choose [0 1]: Adversary replies YES.  (Other answer also leads to height-2 subtree.)
Height=2.  Knowledge state: [5 2]
Choose [0 1]: Adversary replies YES.  (Other answer also leads to height-1 subtree.)
Height=1.  Knowledge state: [5 1]
Choose [0 1]: Adversary replies YES.  (Other answer also leads to height-0 subtree.)
Height=0.  Knowledge state: [5 0]
```

This takes about 16s on my laptop, and uses about 110Mb.  Note that I needed to increase the default stack size (`/L` on MSVC++); with the default of 1Mb, the largest problem that could be tackled without crashing was `5 23`.  I increased it to 512Mb to be on the safe side.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <map>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

bool verbose = false;

//DEBUG: Enable output of vectors
template <typename T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, vector<T>& v) {
    os << '[';
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
        if (i > 0) {
            os << ' ';
        }

        os << v[i];
    }

    os << ']';
    return os;
}

// Call f with every valid choice of items.
template <typename F>
void for_each_choice(vector<unsigned>& v, F f, vector<unsigned>& u, bool takenSomethingYet) {
    unsigned i = u.size();
    if (i == v.size()) {
        // We have chosen amounts to take from every subset.
        if (takenSomethingYet) {
            if (verbose) cerr << "From " << v << " we have chosen " << u << "." << endl;     //DEBUG
            f(u);
        }
    } else {
        // "+ (i == 1)": Only try choosing all the items in a subset for the unknown subset, v[1].
        // "(i <= 2 ... u[i - 1])": For a sequence of equal-size subsets, only choose a nondecreasing sequence of item counts (symmetry).
        u.push_back(0); 
        for (unsigned j = (i <= 2 || v[i] != v[i - 1] ? 0 : u[i - 1]); j < v[i] + (i == 1); ++j) {
            // Try choosing j items from this set
            u.back() = j;
            for_each_choice(v, f, u, takenSomethingYet);
            takenSomethingYet = true;
        }
        u.pop_back();
    }
}

// For convenience.
template <typename F>
void for_each_choice(vector<unsigned>& v, F f) {
    vector<unsigned> u(1, 0);       // First position, where k would be, is ignored
    for_each_choice(v, f, u, false);
}

void normalise(vector<unsigned>& r) {
    if (verbose) cerr << "normalise(" << r << ") called." << endl;       //DEBUG
    // Get rid of all subsets of size 0 or 1.
    unsigned j = 2;
    for (unsigned i = 2; i < r.size(); ++i) {
        if (r[i] <= 1) {
            r[0] -= r[i];       // Decrease k whenever we have a singleton marked subset: its single member must be marked
        } else {
            r[j++] = r[i];
        }
    }
    r.erase(r.begin() + j, r.end());

    // If the maximum possible number of marked elements are already accounted for by disjoint marked subsets, then all "unknown" elements
    // are really known not to be marked.
    if (r.size() == r[0] + 2) {
        r[1] = 0;
    }

    sort(r.begin() + 2, r.end());
    if (verbose) cerr << "Result of normalise(): " << r << "." << endl;       //DEBUG
}

// Return configuration resulting from the adversary saying "yes" to the choice u
vector<unsigned> yes(vector<unsigned> v, vector<unsigned> u) {
    if (verbose) cerr << "From " << v << ", answer YES to " << u << "." << endl;     //DEBUG
    vector<unsigned> r = v;
    for (unsigned i = 1; i < v.size(); ++i) {
        r[i] -= u[i];
    }

    normalise(r);
    return r;
}

// Return configuration resulting from the adversary saying "no" to the choice u
// Note that, because normalise() sets v[1] to 0 if all marked elements are already exhausted by marked disjoint subsets, this function can never
// produce a contradictory knowledge state (that is, one with more than v[0] disjoint marked subsets).
vector<unsigned> no(vector<unsigned> v, vector<unsigned> u) {
    if (verbose) cerr << "From " << v << ", answer NO to " << u << "." << endl;     //DEBUG
    vector<unsigned> r = v;
    r.push_back(0);
    for (unsigned i = 1; i < v.size(); ++i) {
        if (u[i] > 0) {
            r[1] += v[i] - u[i];    // Tricky: In every subset that we chose some elements from, every *unchosen* element goes back in the "we dunno" pile.
            r[i] -= v[i];           // For all i >= 2, this will set r[i] to 0, and this element will be deleted by normalise()
            r.back() += u[i];
        }
    }

    normalise(r);
    return r;
}

// First element is k, the maximum number of marked items.
// Second element is number of items about which we know nothing.
// Remaining items are in sorted order, and are the sizes of disjoint subsets of items: we know that each of these subsets contains at least one marked item.

map<vector<unsigned>, int> memo_;           // Holds solutions already computed
map<vector<unsigned>, vector<unsigned>> nextMove_;      // Holds a best move for already-computed solutions

unsigned solve(vector<unsigned> v) {
    if (verbose) cerr << "solve(" << v << ") called." << endl;      //DEBUG

    auto us = memo_.find(v);
    if (us != memo_.end() && (*us).second == -1) {
        if (verbose) cerr << "solve(" << v << ") returning " << (UINT_MAX - 1) << " because the current state already appeared in the history, indicating an infinite loop." << endl;      //DEBUG
        return UINT_MAX - 1;            // -1 so that it survives the +1 it gets later
    }

    // Because v has been normalised, we have identified all marked states iff there are no unknown elements and no marked subsets.
    if (v.size() == 2 && v[1] == 0) {
        if (verbose) cerr << "solve(" << v << ") returning 0 since no unknown elements could be marked." << endl;      //DEBUG
        return 0;
    }

    if (us == memo_.end()) {
        // Haven't computed the solution to this subproblem yet: do it now
        us = memo_.insert(make_pair(v, -1)).first;      // Tell descendant calls that this state is in the history and would lead to a worst-case infinite loop

        // Generate every possible successor state
        unsigned best = UINT_MAX;
        vector<unsigned> bestMove;
        for_each_choice(v, [&](vector<unsigned> u) {
            unsigned cur = 1U + max(solve(yes(v, u)), solve(no(v, u)));
            if (cur < best) {
                best = cur;
                bestMove = u;
            }
        });

        (*us).second = best;
        nextMove_[v] = bestMove;
    }

    if (verbose) cerr << "solve(" << v << ") returning " << (*us).second << "." << endl;      //DEBUG
    return (*us).second;
}

// You must call solve() first to populate nextMove_[].
void traceBack(vector<unsigned> v) {
    cout << "One possible maximum-length sequence of queries that follow an optimal strategy:\n";
    while (true) {
        unsigned iSteps = solve(v);
        vector<unsigned> u = nextMove_[v];
        cout << "Height=" << iSteps << ".  Knowledge state: " << v << endl;

        if (iSteps == 0) {
            break;
        }

        cout << "Choose " << u << ": Adversary replies ";

        unsigned hYes = solve(yes(v, u));
        unsigned hNo = solve(no(v, u));
        if (hYes == iSteps - 1) {
            cout << "YES.  (Other answer " << (hYes == hNo ? "also " : "") << "leads to height-" << hNo << " subtree.)\n";
            v = yes(v, u);
        } else {
            assert(hNo == iSteps - 1);
            cout << "NO.  (Other answer " << (hYes == hNo ? "also " : "") << "leads to height-" << hNo << " subtree.)\n";
            v = no(v, u);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int nArgs = 0;
    bool showTraceback = false;

    if (string(argv[1]) == "-v") {
        verbose = true;
        ++nArgs;
    }

    if (string(argv[nArgs + 1]) == "-t") {
        showTraceback = true;
        ++nArgs;
    }

    unsigned k = atoi(argv[nArgs + 1]);
    unsigned n = atoi(argv[nArgs + 2]);

    vector<unsigned> v(2);
    v[0] = k;
    v[1] = n;

    normalise(v);       // Needed in case k=0.

    cout << "Minimum number of queries required in the worst case: " <<  solve(v) << endl;

    if (showTraceback) {
        traceBack(v);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'll try the code out this weekend. It's not clear from your trace output what the choose [0,3] means...I'm guessing that means "guess a set with three elements that you haven't seen before"...also, am I reading the trace correctly that the best strategy takes the most steps when the adversary always says YES, i.e. no elements were removed from the initial set?

Comment: "Choose [0 3]" means "Take 3 items from the set of items we know nothing about", which is not necessarily the same as the set of items we haven't seen before (although they mean the same thing until such time as we take items from a set that we know something about).  Although the adversary always YES in this trace, notice that at all but one adversary choice point, choosing NO leads to a tree of the same height, and thus a sequence of the same length.

Comment: I tried out the code and played around with it just a bit, and changing "if (hYes == iSteps -1)" to "if (hYes == iSteps -1 && hYes != hNo)" made the output a lot more interesting for "-t".

It results in the same height of tree, but gives a better description of how the knowledge state changes with both YES and NO answers and how to guess within subsets that were previously guessed but gave a NO.

Comment: Yes, that should add some variety.  It would actually be pretty easy to make that function print out the entire tree -- it could just call itself recursively, with an extra "starting point" parameter, to handle *both* the hYes and hNo cases.  Not sure how to present it "nicely" though (maybe outputting a .dot graph?)